# TSQL Query - Match All Key-Value-Pairs

Tags: sql, t-sql

Given the following table structure where I have an entity with a set of key/value pairs:

[image: Table Records]

How can I construct a query that will return records (distinct EntityIds) for a match of all key/value pairs provided via parameters?

For example, providing "key/value1" and "key/value2" for the example data set should return only the first record ("0E31A033-9A8A-422D-8878-047D4998A23C") since its the only entity that contains both.

Note: for my use-case, dynamic T-SQL is fine so I can work with hard-coding values in responses.

Comment: That's a very bad anti-pattern. It *doesn't* offer any flexibility but it does create huge maintainability, correctness, performance issues. If somethening needs to be part of a query, especially for filtering, it should *not* be stored this way

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: You can use sparse columns to add 60K+ fields to a table that will take only as much space as needed for their storage. Why did you use EAV in the first place?

Comment: You can also use XML fields, in fact sparse columns store their data to a hidden XML field. In SQL Server 2016+ you can use JSON strings for the extra attributes. For the attributes that need indexing, you should use proper fields and tables

Comment: User-defined attributes for the entity. This system has some dynamic elements to it.

Comment: Check [Aaron Bertrand's](https://sqlblog.org/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway) article on cases where EAV makes sense - this is one of them. Note that he uses different fields per *type* though to allow for *some* meaningul indexing and accepts that combining the pairs in a single result will be hard and best left to the client code

Comment: In other words, getting a single row per entity is hard. Better let the client handle it

Comment: Yeah, I agree. This is pretty straight-forward in code but I thought there might be a more efficient way from the DB.

Comment: That's why EAV is considered an *anti*pattern except in specific cases. To reconstruct one row you'd have to return an arbitrary number of fields. Table fields are important though, they have types, constraints, guarantees etc. Perhaps you coudl convert the key/value pairs to XML or JSON and "rehydrate" the attributes on the client ?

Comment: Yeah, that's precisely what I'm going to do. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

```
Select distinct EntityId 
from myTable 
where [Name]='key' and [Value] in ('value1','value2');
```

Looks like I misunderstood:

```
Select distinct t1.EntityId
from myTable t1
inner join myTable t2 on t1.EntityId = t2.EntityId
where t1.[Name] = 'key' and t2.[Name] = 'key'
 and t1.[Value] = 'value1' and t2.Value = 'value2';
```

Or like this:

```
SELECT entityId
 FROM myTable 
 WHERE [Name]='key' AND [Value] IN ('value1','value2')
 GROUP BY entityid
 HAVING COUNT(*)=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
SELECT EntityId FROM TheTable
WHERE Name='key'
and Value IN ('value1','value2')
GROUP BY EntityId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Value) = 2
```